Expo Accepting location permission will make app crash
I have published my app developed with expo on the play store and unfortunately when I open my app and go to the sign up page, it asks me for my location first, I accept and then it crashes. In my local dev environment using the Expo Go app, the component works fine, there's no crashes, I can allow or refuse the permission and the respected code will run, but the problem is in prod for some reason that I can't figure out why? Did someone already have this kind of problem with his expo app in prod? Thank you.
Here's my complete component LocationPicker
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet, Dimensions} from 'react-native';
import MapView, {Marker, Region} from 'react-native-maps';
import * as Location from 'expo-location';
import Loader from "../Loader";

interface LocationPickerProps {
    onLocationSelect?: (location: { latitude: number; longitude: number }) => void;
    selectedLocation?: { latitude: number; longitude: number } | null;
}

const LocationPicker = ({onLocationSelect, selectedLocation}: LocationPickerProps) => {
    const [currentLocation, setCurrentLocation] = useState<Region | null>(null);
    const [marker, setMarker] = useState<{ latitude: number; longitude: number } | null>(null);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
    const [permissionDenied, setPermissionDenied] = useState(false);

    // Effect for requesting location permission and handling location update
    useEffect(() => {
        const requestLocationPermission = async () => {
            try {
                setIsLoading(true);
                const {status} = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
                console.log("STATUS", status);
                if (status !== 'granted') {
                    setPermissionDenied(true);
                    setDefaultLocationOnMap();
                    return;
                }

                // If permissions are granted, fetch the location
                fetchLocation();
            } catch (error) {
                // console.error('Error requesting location permission:', error);
                setDefaultLocationOnMap();
            } finally {
                setIsLoading(false);
            }
        };

        requestLocationPermission();
    }, []);

    // Function to fetch and update location
    const fetchLocation = async () => {
        try {
            if (selectedLocation) {
                const region: Region = {
                    latitude: selectedLocation.latitude,
                    longitude: selectedLocation.longitude,
                    latitudeDelta: 0.01,
                    longitudeDelta: 0.01,
                };
                setCurrentLocation(region);
                setMarker(selectedLocation);
            } else {
                const location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
                if (location && location.coords) {
                    const {latitude, longitude} = location.coords;
                    const region: Region = {
                        latitude,
                        longitude,
                        latitudeDelta: 0.01,
                        longitudeDelta: 0.01,
                    };
                    setCurrentLocation(region);
                    setMarker({latitude, longitude});
                    if (onLocationSelect) {
                        onLocationSelect({latitude, longitude})
                    }
                } else {
                    setDefaultLocationOnMap();
                }
            }
        } catch (error) {
            // console.error('Error getting location:', error);
            setDefaultLocationOnMap();
        }
    };

    const setDefaultLocationOnMap = () => {
        const defaultLocation: Region = {
            latitude: 0,
            longitude: 0,
            latitudeDelta: 0.01,
            longitudeDelta: 0.01,
        };
        setCurrentLocation(defaultLocation);
    };

    const handlePress = (event: any) => {
        const coordinate = event.nativeEvent.coordinate;
        setMarker(coordinate);
        if (onLocationSelect) {
            onLocationSelect(coordinate);
        }
    };

    if (isLoading) {
        return (
            <View style={styles.loadingContainer}>
                <Loader/>
            </View>
        );
    }

    if (permissionDenied) {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <MapView
                    style={styles.map}
                    initialRegion={currentLocation!}
                    onPress={handlePress}
                >
                    {marker && <Marker coordinate={marker}/>}
                </MapView>
            </View>
        );
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            {currentLocation && (
                <MapView
                    style={styles.map}
                    initialRegion={currentLocation}
                    onPress={handlePress}
                >
                    {marker && <Marker coordinate={marker}/>}
                </MapView>
            )}
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    map: {
        width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
        flex: 1,
    },
    loadingContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
});

export default LocationPicker;


Is it that default location?

Default location was omitted, I just put 0,0
